# How do we can draw arrows, spacing arrows with or without arrow head/tail in react js?

Tags: reactjs, canvas, drawing, react-konva

I want to make a canvas where user can draw shapes like rectangles, circles, arrows with or without arrow head/tail and drag icons in order to make an image in react js. So far I have implemented the drag functionality to store icons in an array and save their positions on drop or on changing positions. I have used `react-konva` to draw rectangles/circles/drawing/straight lines. It's not best but good for certain shapes.

**How do I achieve drawing arrows?** I just need hints about best libraries.

I tried drawing arrows using canvas only but it's not giving best output.

Thank you so much for reading. If anyone can help it would be great in completing my project.